# Issue with joins in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT  
    c.ConfigurationID AS RealflowID, c.companyname, 
    c.companyphone, c.ContactEmail, COUNT(k.caseid)
FROM    
    dbo.Configuration c
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cases k ON k.SiteID = c.ConfigurationId
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.RepairEstimates
            WHERE caseid = k.caseid)
    AND c.AccountStatus = 'Active' 
    AND c.domainid = 46
GROUP BY 
    c.configurationid,c.companyname, c.companyphone, c.ContactEmail
```

I have this query - I am using the configuration table to get the `siteid` of the cases in the cases table. And if the case exists in the repair estimates table pull the company details listed and get a count of how many cases are in the repair estimator table for that `siteid`.

I hope that is clear enough of a description.

But the issue here is the count is not correct with the data that is being pulled. Is there something I could do differently? Different join? Remove the exists add another join? I am not sure I have tried many different things.

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful here to explain your question.

Comment: So like you mean what each table means? or something like that.

Comment: As I see it, the query is doing what you want. Can you provide simple example data. A few rows will help to see what do you expect, and what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I was using the wrong table. The query was correct.